# Python code doesn't call class from another program when Import statement is used

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to write a code a that gets user input via pop up and use that in different program.
below is the code which gets user input.

**Excel_connection.py**

```
import openpyxl
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        #Create a blank dictionary
        self.answers = {}
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)

        tk.Label(self,text="Give Input Sheet Path").grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Input_From_User1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input_From_User1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        tk.Button(self,text="Feed into Program",command = 
        self.collectAnswers).grid(row=2,column=1)

    def collectAnswers(self):
        self.answers['Input_Path'] = self.Input_From_User1.get()
        global Input_Path
        Input_Path = self.answers['Input_Path']
        functionThatUsesAnswers(self.answers)
        quit()  
    def quit():
    root.destroy()        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path) # trying to open the open the input sheet from the 
below path
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
```

Below is the code where i'm importing the above program which does some operation

**Execution.py**

```
import pandas
from Excel_Connection import *
from Snowflake_Connection import *

all_rows = list(ws.rows)
cur = ctx.cursor()
# Pull information from specific cells.
for row in all_rows[1:400]:
    scenario = row[1].value
    query = row[2].value
    if_execute = row[3].value
    if if_execute == 'Y':
        try:
            cur.execute(query)
            df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
        except:
            print(scenario," Failed")
        else:
            print("CREATED",scenario,".csv successfully")
print("ALL INDIVDUAL REPORT GENERATED")
```

When I'm executing **Execution.py**, the program does not produce pop up window and instead the code throws below error,

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path) # trying to open the open the input sheet from the below path
NameError: name 'Input_Path' is not defined
```

I tried to -

1. executing **Excel_connection.py** separately and it just worked fine.
2. place the code directly instead of importing the program in the **Execution.py** and again it worked fine as expected.

The only time I'm facing issue is when I try to import the **Excel_connection.py** into **Excel_connection.py**

Could somebody kindly help me out here.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

When you import Excel_connection.py, it'll run the code in it.
So as you run Execution.py:

1. import pandas -> "run" the pandas stuff to define functions, etc...
2. from Excel_connection import * -> You import everything from Excel_connection. So the interpreter will open this file, parse, and run:
   2.1 Class App is defined
   2.2 runs: `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path)`, which is a nonsense. Since as I see Input_Path is defined in App.collectAnswers(), which was never executed before. So there is no Input_Path to use... And you program terminates here, and tells you that.

If you run your Excel_connection.py directly, it'll work, because the `if __name__ == '__main__'` is True in this case and that section runs too. But if you import the file, it is false so you skip that part of the code.

You should move this to the Execution.py file before the `all_rows = list(ws.rows)` line

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path) # trying to open the open the input sheet from the 
below path
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
```

And it'll still break since we have no Input_Path, so you must define it somehow, but it is up to you how. You can create an App like how you do it in the `Excel_connection.py`.

But I shouldn't do that since it is a little ugly. I would do something like:
**Excel_Connection.py**

```
import openpyxl
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        #Create a blank dictionary
        self.answers = {}
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)

        tk.Label(self,text="Give Input Sheet Path").grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Input_From_User1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input_From_User1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        tk.Button(self,text="Feed into Program",command = 
        self.collectAnswers).grid(row=2,column=1)

    def collectAnswers(self):
        self.answers['Input_Path'] = self.Input_From_User1.get()
        global Input_Path
        Input_Path = self.answers['Input_Path']
        functionThatUsesAnswers(self.answers)
        self.quit()

    # def quit():
    #     root.destroy()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path) # trying to open the open the input sheet from the below path
    return wb["Sheet1"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then
**Execution.py**

```
import pandas
import Excel_Connection
from Snowflake_Connection import *

# Now we call the main() function from Excel_Connection, which will return the worksheet for us.
ws = Excel_Connection.main()

all_rows = list(ws.rows)
cur = ctx.cursor()
# Pull information from specific cells.
for row in all_rows[1:400]:
    scenario = row[1].value
    query = row[2].value
    if_execute = row[3].value
    if if_execute == 'Y':
        try:
            cur.execute(query)
            df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
        except:
            print(scenario," Failed")
        else:
            print("CREATED",scenario,".csv successfully")
print("ALL INDIVDUAL REPORT GENERATED")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought I have defined the class and executing it. I came to this conclusion since I m getting th desired result if I run the program separately. Could you please advise what I'll have to do make this code work. I'm new to python so your guidance would be really useful.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope It can help. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Comment: It still throws Inputh_Path not defined error :(. Is it something to do with Destroy Object i'm using to close the Pop Up window

Comment: @sh1704 Oh sry I see, there is an indentiation error. I corrected that. in the `def quit():` function I have missed 4 spaces before `root.destroy()`. But as I see there will be other undefined stuff too... `functionThatUsesAnswers`
And you don't need that whole quit() function since it does nothing but I'm not so familiar with tkinter. But for me it is working without that. Since root is also not defined in it. So you need to store that to call quit on that.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

> csv files

or some file format like that to store and transfer data between files.